# Drupal Views and Content Taxonomy

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, cck, drupal-taxonomy

I have been searching all morning and have yet to come across the solution for my problem..

problem is:
I have successfully created a  CCK content type using the content taxonomy module (which allows me to use a vocabulary as the content). the user is asked to select his/her preferred cultures. so in simple terms form holding a series of checkboxes which the user merely selects their preferred cultures.

problem comes when I wish to display the selected cultures by that user for them to then sort into their top 5 cultures.

the sorting bit I can do using draggable views. however actually displaying the users selected cultures is something im finding difficult.

sorry for my novice of a question.. but its been one of those days.

Comment: Where are you trying to display them?

Comment: on a separate page. using views.

Answer (score 0):

You should use relationships.

- **HOWTO: Views 2 Relationships**: http://drewish.com/node/127
- **User Relationships** module: http://drupal.org/project/user_relationships
- http://www.drupalforusers.com/content/using-views-2-relationships
- **Using Drupal's Views Relationships**: http://www.drupalove.com/drupal-video/using-drupals-views-relationships

Also you may need this patch: http://drupal.org/node/241078.
Or a module that allows to make backrelationships but it is private.